# RecyclerView showing two highlighted item

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, adapter, onclicklistener

I have two scenario to highlight the item in recyclerview first one is when user click on any item so that clicked item should be highlighted and and second scenario is when last or recent item added into the list that time that last added item should be highlighted.

So my first scenario(onClick) is working fine but problem is in my second scenario so whenever I'm adding item into the list so two items are highlighted. Please suggest me where I am wrong. and one more thing that recent or last item should be perform auto click also. so How can I achieve it.

```
class CarItemAdapter(
        private val activity: MainActivity,
        private val carList: ArrayList<CarEntity>,
        private val carViewModel: CarViewModel,
        private val settings: Settings
) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    var listener: OnItemsClickListener? = null
    var rowIndex = 100
    var listItemCount = 0

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return when (viewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_ADDITEM -> ViewHolderAddCarItem(SettingsCarAddItemTileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false))
            VIEW_TYPE_ITEM -> ViewHolderCarItem(SettingsCarItemTileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false))
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolderCarItem -> holder.bind(carList[position -1], position-1)
            is ViewHolderAddCarItem -> holder.bind()
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolderAddCarItem internal constructor(private var binding: SettingsCarAddItemTileBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind() {
            binding.lifecycleOwner = activity
            binding.handler = EventHandler()
            binding.userSpecificCarSubtitle.setText(R.string.user_specific_car_subtitle)
        }

        inner class EventHandler {
            fun onItemClicked() {
                activity.showSubPage(Car360AddVehiclePage(activity), true)
            }
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolderCarItem internal constructor(private var binding: SettingsCarItemTileBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(carEntity: CarEntity, position: Int) {
            Timber.d("Data store position %s %s", position, carList.size)
            listItemCount = itemCount

            binding.lifecycleOwner = activity
            val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(carEntity.image, 0, Objects.requireNonNull<ByteArray>(carEntity.image).size)
            binding.carImage.setImageBitmap(bmp)
            binding.carName.text = carEntity.label

            binding.layoutCar.setOnClickListener {
                listItemCount = 100
                listener?.onItemClick(carEntity)
                settings.finNumber = carEntity.finNumber
                settings.selectedCarType = activity.getString(R.string.settings_category_view_sub_title_for_user_specific_car)
                settings.isCarSelected = true
                rowIndex = position
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            binding.deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { carViewModel.deleteByFinNumber(carEntity.finNumber) }
                carList.removeAt(position)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            if(position == listItemCount-2){
                binding.layoutCar.setBackgroundColor(activity.getColor(R.color.petrol))
                binding.carName.setTextColor(activity.getColor(R.color.white))
            }else{
                binding.layoutCar.setBackgroundColor(activity.getColor(R.color.coolGray))
                binding.carName.setTextColor(activity.getColor(R.color.coolGray_80k))
            }

            if (rowIndex == position) {
                binding.layoutCar.setBackgroundColor(activity.getColor(R.color.petrol))
                binding.carName.setTextColor(activity.getColor(R.color.white))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == 0 && position <= carList.size) {
            VIEW_TYPE_ADDITEM
        } else VIEW_TYPE_ITEM
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return carList.size + 1
    }

    interface OnItemsClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(carEntity: CarEntity)
    }

    fun setWhenClickListener(listener: OnItemsClickListener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    companion object {
        const val VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0
        const val VIEW_TYPE_ADDITEM = 1
    }
}
```

MyFragmentSubPage : where I'm adding data into the list

```
 if (isDialogVisible) {
            Dialog imageDownloadCheckDialog = Dialog.createProgressBarDialog(getContext(), R.string.image_progressbar_title);
            imageDownloadCheckDialog.setCancelable(false);
            imageDownloadCheckDialog.show();
            carViewModel.getGetDismissDialog().observe(getActivity(), isDismissDialog -> {
                if (isDismissDialog) {
                    imageDownloadCheckDialog.dismiss();
                    carViewModel.dismissDialog(false);
                    new Thread(() -> {
                        CarEntity carEntity = carViewModel.getImageFor340Degree(vinNumber, "340");
                        // Here I am adding data into the list
                        recyclerImageList.add(carEntity);
                    }).start();
                }

            });
        }
        
          RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.list);
        if (recyclerView != null) {
            layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }

  carItemAdapter = new CarItemAdapter(getActivity(), recyclerImageList, eventHandler, carViewModel, settings);
            assert recyclerView != null;
            recyclerView.setAdapter(carItemAdapter);
            recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(carItemAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_ITEM, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a `CarEntity` var inside your adapter called `selectedCar`.

Make a function inside your adapter called `submitItem`

```
  fun submitItem(car: CarEntity) {
            selectedCar = car //set the selected car to the new car
            notifyItemChanged(rowIndex)//rebind old selected car
            carList.add(car) //add new car to list
            rowIndex = carList.size() - 1 //set current selected index
            notifyItemInserted(rowIndex)//notify the change at selected index
    }
```

And your dialog

```
                new Thread(() -> {
                    CarEntity carEntity = carViewModel.getImageFor340Degree(vinNumber, "340");
                    // Here I am adding data into the list
                    requireActivity().runOnUiThread{
                          carItemAdapter.submitItem(carEntity);   
                    }
                }).start();
```

and your button

```
binding.layoutCar.setOnClickListener {
                listItemCount = 100
                listener?.onItemClick(carEntity)
                settings.finNumber = carEntity.finNumber
                settings.selectedCarType = activity.getString(R.string.settings_category_view_sub_title_for_user_specific_car)
                

                selectedCar = carEntity //set the select car on click
                notifyItemChanged(rowIndex) //notify old row has changed
                notifyItemChanged(position) //notify new row has changed
                rowIndex = position // set current selected row
            }
```

and on bind to set selected view stuff

```
if(carEntity == selectedCar){
    //highlight row
}
```

Comment: So are you saying if you have `5` items and select item `1`, then add an item now item `5` and `6` are selected OR are items `1` and `6` selected.

Comment: I'm saying if I have 5 items in list then I'm adding 6th item in list so 5th and 6th getting highlighted instead of 6th one. Here I'm not clicking or selecting on item.

Comment: just whenever I'm adding data into the list that recent item should be selected and as I have already motioned in question I have 2 scenario one is onClick I have to highlighted selected item and second is if data adding into the list that time that recent item should be highlighted

Comment: Can you post the piece of code where you add items to the list and notify the adapter of the change?

Comment: getting issue while implementing the same logic "    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." in this line         notifyItemChanged(rowIndex)//rebind old selected car

Comment: `carItemAdapter.submitItem(carEntity); ` make sure you run the new adapter function on the UI thread.  `requireActivity().runOnUiThread { //here }`

Comment: yes did the same now not getting that issue. tried to implement your logic but item is not getting highlighted. Something issue with the position I guess.

Comment: Yea its really hard to tell. I would avoid complex position based logic, as you are doing a lot of position finagling. I can't tell exactly what the Settings object does but from the looks of it, its redundant and probably should be removed.   In short streamline the selection process. `var selectedCar` should keep track of the selection. The `CarEntity` received at bind is the only thing that should determine what is displayed. Any time you change something notify the adapter of the change.

Comment: okay...settings object I have used for some other purpose not related to highlighting the color. yeah you are correct I was playing with position only but I have tried your logic also but didn't get any success